# Waiting for multiple cUrls from PHP and when is too much?

Tags: php, api, curl

I have created a "boggle"-like game for personal programming practice/portfolio.

I found a free API where I can verify words.

My question: if 3 players each have 15-20 words and a script starts running the calls to the api (it's an unlimited use API as far as I can tell from research), then is there a "guarantee" that every call will run? How does php compare to JS's promise/asyncronous style? Is there anything to worry about with a lot of cUrls in a row? How many requests/responses can an instance of php handle at one time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP code runs asynchronously, if you are using standard [`curl_exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php), then it will only process one request at a time, and the only limit for a single script is how long the calls take, and the [configured time limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php).

If you are using [`curl_multi_exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php) then you can make asynchronous requests, and there is theoretically no limit, but it is dependent on a number of other factors, such as available bandwidth etc, limits of number of network connections and/or open files on your system.

Some relevant info [here](https://curl.haxx.se/mail/archive-2008-10/0038.html):

```
libcurl itself has no particular limits, if you're referring to amount of 
concurrent transfer/handles or so. Your system/app may have a maximum amount 
of open file handles that'll prevent you from adding many thousands. Also, 
when going beyond a few hundred handles the regular curl_multi_perform() 
approach start to show that it isn't suitable for many transfers and you 
should rather switch to curl_multi_socket() - which I unfortunately believe 
the PHP binding has no support for.
```

Comment: So is php curl asnyc? I'm reading that it is synchronous, which is fine... I think I can get all the responses I need in 30 seconds of the max_limit(which is 30 in my phpinfo)

Comment: curl can be async if you use curl_multi_exec see example on linked documentation page

Comment: This article explains the curl_multi_exec approach well http://www.adrianworlddesign.com/Knowledge-Base/php/Download-content-with-cURL/Doing-curlmultiexec-the-right-way